# Heading and span on the same line

Tags: html, css

I am generating divs dynamically and need a solution exactly like this (no external style or css because they are ignored when generated dynamically after page load). I don't understand why the browser ignore my text-align:right. Also i want to keep h and span (no p). Normally we should see h to the left and span to the right on the same baseline:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>

<div style="background-color:green;color:white;">
  <h1 style="display:inline">Green, color of hope</h1>
  <span style="text-align:right">I hope to display this to the right</span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `text-align: right` aligns inline content to the right of a block element with the attribute. span is inline. have you tried `float: left` on the h1 and `float: right` on the span and `overflow: hidden` on the wrapper div. that said you should probably aim for more semantic markup instead, linked stylesheets shouldnt be ignored either... dynamic content isn't really an excuse for poor markup

Comment: From what i had tried friday, anything i would add between style tags (or in a css sheet) would be ignored on elements dynamically added after page load so i though it was normal and only inline style would work at that point. No i didn' t had great success with float either, cause the text on the right to align top not baseline...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tuned alot and decide to use this as the simpliest solution to my problem. Note that as many solutions are proposed around the web, rare are those adressing (in a simple way) the problem for items to be baseline aligned while being of different sizes:

```
<style>
    .left{text-align:left;font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;}
    .right{float:right;font-size:14px;padding-top:4px}
</style>   

<span class='left'>Left</span><span class='right'>Right</span>
```

Answer (score 6):

Flexbox can do that:

```html
<div style="background-color:green;color:white; display:flex; justify-content:space-between; align-items:baseline;">
  <h1>Green, color of hope</h1>
  <span>I hope to display this to the right</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I am running the snippet right now and right text aligns in the middle, not at baseline. I will try it tomorrow on my real target. Thanxs.